# Structure of web service to integrate two REST APIs

Tags: c#, rest, api

I am writing a program that will be used to pull data from two separate SaaS softwares via their REST APIs - concatenate them, and save the output as raw JSON. When this is complete - the program will be scheduled to run every night.

The overall concept isn't really complicated, it follows a very simple process:

1. Pull data from **Software A** via REST
2. Pull data from **Software B** via REST
3. Concatenate them
4. Save output as raw JSON

I started off by trying to develop this as a .NET Core Console Application. Mostly straightforward - just using appropriate libraries to send/receive HTTP requests to both software APIs, pulling data, and using IO library to save to JSON file.

However - I've been told that this actually needs to be a web service, not a console application. I have basic experience and knowledge regarding web services, but I need some help understanding how to lay out the entire solution from a high-level.

I think I'm getting confused at understanding how exactly web services work and how my original solution would fit into a web service? And how would my final solution be "deployed" and scheduled to run?

How would I structure the 4 step process above if I were to convert my console application to a web service?

Comment: A web service is just a platform that will run the lines of code you've already written on a regular basis. You could do it by deploying it to regularly-running Azure Functions, or a webjob, or there are other methods that people employ. If you work somewhere, ask a more senior dev how you'd deploy the code you've written.

Comment: Are you planning to deploy this to Azure?

Comment: The OP never mentions Azure. You can definitely use a dotnet core console application to consume both REST APIs and save the file where you need it. That console app can then be executed every night via Task Scheduler. Pretty simple actually, you're on the right track.